# Making an Existing project a static framework in XCODE

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I have a project that I want to share with other developers ( like a third party library ) .

this project exposes a web service that I own and is private, now one easy way to share the project is to add them on my private github repo and have them download and drag and drop it into their own project. I don't want that, but want to package it as a framework. I am familiar with Ray wenderlich [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios) on how to build a framework, but that one forces you to create a brand new project and make that the framework. In XCode I can add another target that is a static framework to my existing project, shouldn't that do the job? where can I inspect the output of that target?

Am I making the wrong assumptions? I don;t want to follow the ray wenderlich tutorial because I want to understand why do I have the abiity to add a target to my existing project ??

Comment: Have you found any solution?